# In Next.js getServerSideProps, how can I fetch cookie from browser to identify the user

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, next.js

I am developing an e-commerce site. A user has selected the items. To view his cart and checkout he clicks on the cart icon in `NavBar` which navigates him to `myCart.js` page. I am using `getServerSideProps` to get JWT from the browser, decode it and verify the user. Code is as below:

```
let jwtoken;
export async function getServerSideProps(req, res) {

  if (
    req.headers.authorization &&
    req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')
  ) {
    jwtoken = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  } else if (req.cookies.jwt) {
    jwtoken = req.cookies.jwt;
  }

  if (!jwtoken) {
    return res.status(423).redirect('/emptyCart');

  const decoded = await promisify(jwt.verify)(jwtoken, process.env.JWT_SECRET);

  currentUser = await User.findById(decoded.id);

  if (!currentUser) 
    return res.status(401).redirect('/signup');
```

Note: cookie is httpOnly.

I get a runtime error: `'headers not defined'` 
Now if I remove the code containing `req.headers` and use only `eq.cookies.jwt` > gives me another error cookies not defined.

I worked on this issue for four days and tried so many solutions offered in Stackoverflow and also from other developer portals like `flavio`, `reddit` and others.

Comment: are you passing this middleware i.e getServerSideProps in request

Answer (score 2):

The `getServerSideProps` function expects a single `context` parameter, which contains the `req`/`res` objects you're trying to access.

Change your `getServerSideProps` function to have the following signature:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
    console.log(req.cookies); // Logs all cookies from the request
}
```